# Has anyone ever thrown a 4-out immaculate inning?

Tags: baseball, mlb

Has any pitcher ever thrown a 4-out immaculate inning, and if so, was it still considered immaculate?

That is 4 strikeouts on 12 pitches, with one batter having reached due to a wild pitch.

Comment: I can't imagine the second part of your question having a useful answer - it's not a technical term.

Comment: Just as it would eliminate a perfect game, I would suggest that an error would also eliminate and immaculate inning. Noted that the feat is possible, but the terminology can never be used.

Comment: For those not too familiar with baseball, can you explain more how there would be 4 strikeouts with 12 pitches in 1 inning (well, actually, I think that would be half an inning)?

Comment: If on strike 3, the ball is not caught and first base is open (except when there's 2 outs, it doesn't matter if first is open), the batter becomes a runner, and can run to first base. If he makes it there before he's either tagged or the ball is thrown to the base, he is safe. But the pitcher is still credited with the strike out. Hence getting 4 strikeouts in an inning. It's been done before, but apparently never on 12 pitches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There has never been an MLB immaculate inning with four outs.

Every source available on immaculate innings is quick to list those pitchers who had managed the feat more than once at that point, and annotate additional information that is tangential to the feat, but none (especially from MLB themselves) refer to an inning where more than three strikeouts occur.

While impossible to prove a negative, this is very strong evidence that the feat has not occurred.

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for a comment)

Wikipedia claims

> [N]o player has ever struck out four batters on twelve pitches in an inning.

in its [List of Major League Baseball pitchers who have thrown an immaculate inning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Major_League_Baseball_pitchers_who_have_thrown_an_immaculate_inning), referencing four sources but I could not find the claim in any of them.